# C#, saving from menu strip, and save as button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to save my rich text box content to a a file. However I am getting the error when I am trying to save a new file. Save as works as expected. Any suggestions. Thank you

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Empty path name is not legal.'
```

My code for the save and save as button are as follows:

```
OpenFileDialog file_open = new OpenFileDialog();
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            string filename = "";

            // To filter files from SaveFileDialog
            saveDlg.Filter = "Rich Text File (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Plain Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveDlg.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
            saveDlg.FilterIndex = 1;
            saveDlg.Title = "Save the contents";

            filename = file_open.FileName;

            RichTextBoxStreamType stream_type;
            // Checks the extension of the file to save
            if (filename.Contains(".txt"))
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText;
            else
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText;

            richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, stream_type);




        }

 private void saveAsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog saveDlg = new SaveFileDialog();
            string filename = "";

            // To filter files from SaveFileDialog
            saveDlg.Filter = "Rich Text File (*.rtf)|*.rtf|Plain Text File (*.txt)|*.txt";
            saveDlg.DefaultExt = "*.rtf";
            saveDlg.FilterIndex = 1;
            saveDlg.Title = "Save the contents";

            DialogResult retval = saveDlg.ShowDialog();
            if (retval == DialogResult.OK)
                filename = saveDlg.FileName;
            else
                return;

            RichTextBoxStreamType stream_type;
            if (saveDlg.FilterIndex == 2)
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText;
            else
                stream_type = RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText;

            richTextBox1.SaveFile(filename, stream_type);
            MessageBox.Show("File Saved");
        }
```

Comment: You never show the SaveDialog in the first block, and file_open is never used.  Create one method or function that does this work and then have the menu and the button call that code.  Less code.

Comment: Seems file_open.FileName is null. Validate the value before calling SaveFile method and try to figure out (what you're doing wrong) why it's null.

Comment: Hint: You should save 'filename' in a field, so you can use it in 'filesave'.

Comment: fileName is null, since I am not opening a file, any way to check if the file name is new, and if so, implement the save_as function?

Comment: A "Save" menu should not open a dialog. It should just save the file. So the "Save" menu should be disabled until the file name is known. That file name should have come from a previous call to "Save As" or "Open". Maybe have a field `string currentFileName`.

Comment: @PoulBak I changed filename="Document" and still it gives errors

Comment: 'filename' should should contain the full path, like 'C:\Documents\MyFile.txt'.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp thanks a lot. I have fixed the issue using the currentFileName :D